# How to add black lines to stacked pandas area plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to add separating black lines to a Python area plot created using `pandas`. In other words, I want the stacked areas to be separated by black lines.

My current code is the following:

```
figure1=mydataframe.plot(kind='area', stacked=True)
```

And I am looking for an additional argument to pass on to the function, such as:

```
figure1=mydataframe.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, blacklines=TRUE)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using `pandas` or additional `matplotlib` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `plt.stackplot()`. You can control line width and color with `linewidth` and `edgecolor` arguments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(data))
plt.stackplot(np.arange(10),[df[0],df[1],df[2]])
plt.show()
```

[image: stackplot with black lines]